# Nginx - SSL forward secrecy and iOS9 support

Tags: nginx, ssl, openssl, tls, ios

I'm trying to bring a couple of Linux web servers into line with the current recommendations for SSL - in particular for allowing iOS9 to connect.

One server is CentOS 7, the other CentOS 6.4. I have the CentOS 7 machine configured nicely now, with a nice green A on ssllabs.com. However, on the CentOS 6.4 box (using identical ssl_protocols, ssl_ciphers and ssl_dhparm), I get an A- with the message "The server does not support Forward Secrecy with the reference browsers". In the handshake simulation section of the ssllabs report, Apple ATS 9 / iOS 9 is failing.

ssllabs list the UA capabilities of iOS9 as:

```
TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV (0xff)        -
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc02c)   Forward Secrecy  256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02b)   Forward Secrecy  128
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc024)   Forward Secrecy  256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc00a)   Forward Secrecy     256
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc023)   Forward Secrecy  128
TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc009)   Forward Secrecy     128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   Forward Secrecy    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   Forward Secrecy    128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   Forward Secrecy    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)   Forward Secrecy    128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   Forward Secrecy   128
```

Here are my nginx settings:

```
ssl_protocols               TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;

ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK';
```

When I check the cipher suites that the above will result in, I get the same result on both servers:

```
# openssl ciphers -V  'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK'
      0xC0,0x2F - ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
      0xC0,0x2B - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
      0xC0,0x30 - ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
      0xC0,0x2C - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
      0x00,0x9E - DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
      0x00,0xA2 - DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(128) Mac=AEAD
      0x00,0xA3 - DHE-DSS-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
      0x00,0x9F - DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AESGCM(256) Mac=AEAD
      0xC0,0x27 - ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
      0xC0,0x23 - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
      0xC0,0x13 - ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
      0xC0,0x09 - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
      0xC0,0x28 - ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
      0xC0,0x24 - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384 TLSv1.2 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA384
      0xC0,0x14 - ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA    SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
      0xC0,0x0A - ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA  SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
      0x00,0x67 - DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
      0x00,0x33 - DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA1
      0x00,0x40 - DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(128)  Mac=SHA256
      0x00,0x6B - DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256   TLSv1.2 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA256
      0x00,0x38 - DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=DSS  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
      0x00,0x39 - DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA      SSLv3 Kx=DH       Au=RSA  Enc=AES(256)  Mac=SHA1
```

That seems good to me, as I see some of the cipher suites that iOS9 supports included in that list. I guess it also rules out an issue down to different versions of openssl on the two servers?

And yet the ssllabs report for the two servers shows different lists of cipher suites detected. For my CentOS machine:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0xc02f)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0xc030)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)   DH 2048 bits   FS  128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f)   DH 2048 bits   FS  256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0xc027)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0xc013)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   128
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (0xc028)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS    256
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0xc014)   ECDH secp256r1 (eq. 3072 bits RSA)   FS   256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x67)   DH 2048 bits   FS  128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)   DH 2048 bits   FS     128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x6b)   DH 2048 bits   FS  256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)   DH 2048 bits   FS     256
```

For the failing CentOS 6.4 box:

```
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (0x9e)   DH 2048 bits   FS  128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (0x9f)   DH 2048 bits   FS  256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (0x67)   DH 2048 bits   FS  128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA (0x33)   DH 2048 bits   FS     128
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (0x6b)   DH 2048 bits   FS  256
TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA (0x39)   DH 2048 bits   FS     256
```

All I can think is that it's down to different versions of nginx. The CentOS 6.4 box runs 1.3.0, the CentOS 7 box nginx 1.9.4, yet in my Googling I haven't come anything to back this up.

Am I barking up the wrong tree thinking it's down to the nginx version? I can't see what else it could be.

Comment: nginx added ECDHE support in version 1.1.0. The version of openssl linked to nginx may not have ECDHE enabled.